# How to get form values in Symfony 4 controller with form builder

Tags: php, symfony-forms, builder, symfony4

I want to update data and I need to use form builder for creating form. I saw similar questions but it don't work for me.

My form builder. I think it's all right.

```
class GeneralInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, ['label' => false])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['label' => false])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([

        ]);
    }
}
```

My form on twig. I send id current user on form.

```
 {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('updateInfo',{'id':users.id}), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
 {{ form_row(form.username, {'value' : users.username, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
 {{ form_row(form.email, {'value' : users.email, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } )  }}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

My controller.

```
/**
     * @Route("user/profile/{id}", name="updateInfo")
     * @param $id
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updatePersonalInfoAction($id, Request $request)
    {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $user = $em->getRepository('App:User')->find($id);
       $form = $this->createForm(GeneralInfoType::class, $user);
       $username = $form->get('username')->getData();
       dump($username);
     }
```

When I try dump username I got `""` or null from server.

Comment: Your code never renders the form, much less processes the submission, it only creates the form. If you are doing those things in some other (unshown) part of your code then that would be the place to have access to the form's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("user/profile/{id}", name="updateInfo")
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function updatePersonalInfoAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $user = $em->getRepository('App:User')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(GeneralInfoType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        $username = $form->get('username')->getData();
        dump($username);

        // you can save the update user info with this:
        $user = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return $this->render('insert_twig_file_path/name', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
 }
```

You can also take advantage of some automagical symfony functions to simplify a bit:

```
/**
 * @Route("user/profile/{id}", name="updateInfo")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param User $user
 * @return Response
 */
public function updatePersonalInfoAction(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(GeneralInfoType::class, $user);

    ... the rest unchanged ...

 }
```